# Is .create method adding nil value if it fails to recognize an integer in Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In my controller, I need to pluck a single, matching integer value and then create a record with that value in another table. In action, it looks like this:

```
  if Participation.where(ranking: "1")
      first = PointsAllocation.where(game_id: params[:game_id]).where(place: "1").pluck(:points)
      Stack.create(game_id: params[:game_id], user_id: current_user.id, chips: first)
    else

    end
```

I have tested in the console that the `first` variable is definable. If I run `PointsAllocation.where(game_id: "1").where(place: "1").pluck(:points)`, it will return:

`SELECT "points_allocations"."points" FROM "points_allocations" WHERE "points_allocations"."game_id" = 1 AND "points_allocations"."place" = 1
 => [10]`

Ok, so it is correctly plucking what looks like an integer value for `Points`. I then want to use this points value and send it to the `Chips` column in the `Stack` table. When I run this, it will add a `nil` record even though `first` is defined, like so:

`<Stack id: 1, game_id: 1, user_id: 1, chips: nil>`

In troubleshooting, I thought maybe the issue here is that even though it looks like an integer (and `Chips`, I should add, is a `t.integer` attribute), maybe it's accidentally a string or something from pluck. So let's map this to an integer to be safe by adding `map(&:to_i)` after the pluck.

When I do that, it gets weirder, as it now returns:

`<Stack id: 9, game_id: 1, user_id: 1, chips: 0>`

So when I convert it to an integer, it changes 10 to a 0 and adds it to the table.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may resolve it loading only one object instead `ActiveRecord::Association`:

```
first = PointsAllocation.where(game_id: params[:game_id]).where(place: "1").first
points = first.points 
Stack.create(game_id: params[:game_id], user_id: current_user.id, chips: points)
```

Problem is that AR trying convert incorrect values if they type different with column type:

```
Stack.create(chips: 10)
#=> <Stack id: ..., chips: 10>
Stack.create(chips: [10])
#=> <Stack id: ..., chips: nil>
Stack.create(chips: "10")
#=> <Stack id: ..., chips: 10>
Stack.create(chips: "first")
#=> <Stack id: ..., chips: 0>
```

Comment: Yep, just caught it. An alternative: after reading the documentation, `pluck` will return an array even if it is just one value. By using `.first`, it converts to an integer and can be used in the create method successfully. Thanks!